# Why is Andersen's algorithm for pointer analysis iterative?

Tags: algorithm, pointers, static-analysis, static-code-analysis

Andersen's pointer analysis loops over the program multiple times and represents points-to relations in a graph. It iterates over the code until the points-to graph does not change anymore. I came across the following example from 
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~fischer/cs701.f14/7.POINTER-ANALYSIS.html#andersen

```
p = &a;
p = &b;
m = &p;
r = *m;
q = &c;
m = &q;
```

In this case the points-to relation 'r points to c' is the only relation that is added to the graph after the second iteration. However, a precise outcome would be that r points to b after executing this code. So the second iteration makes the outcome less precise.

I understand that a completely precise pointer analysis does not exist so that points-to sets are an overestimation. But I have looked for many examples and it seems as if the extra iteration always makes the outcomes more imprecise. So why iterate multiple times? Wouldn't one iteration be sound and more precise?

I expect that there must be a reason for this so there must exist cases in which one iteration misses certain points-to relations that actually are true. Can someone come up with an example in which a true points-to relation is not found (i.e. the outcome is not sound) after the first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

This Andersen's analysis is flow-*in*sensitive. It has no notion of control-flow and treats all instructions (statements) as a part of a set.

In your example, the analysis cannot determine that `r` only points to `b` in any real execution because it does not encode what comes first between the statements, so it conservatively assumes that any order can occur. (Similar to how the first iteration found `r = { a, b }` and `p = { a, b }` despite it being obvious to any person that `r` and `p` would only point to `b` at execution.)

To solve this problem as you would like to, you need flow-sensitive analysis, which operates on, at least as an aide, a data structure encoding control-flow, like a control-flow graph, and maintains multiple points-to sets for each memory object (in the most naive way, a points-to set for each memory object at each program-point, but there are ways to carry around less information).

You can take a look at *Flow-sensitive pointer analysis for millions of lines of code* by Hardekopf and Lin (a draft is freely available on the second author's website). If you can get an intuition for the def-use graph they describe and the notation they use, you can work through the algorithm in Section V.

The downside of flow-sensitive points-to analysis is that it is much more expensive, in both time and space. I believe there is a lot of room to bring cost down, however. There are also other precision dimensions: field-sensitivity, context-sensitivity, path-sensitivity, and others.

As for your last point, imagine the last three statements were in a loop. In a real execution, `r` would point to `b` in the first loop iteration, and `c` in every other iteration. The first iteration of Andersen's in your link does not capture this.